# wrong argument type Symbol (expected String) when calling devise sign_out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using rails 3.2 on ruby 1.8.7 and I am upgrading to 1.9.3
one of my first problems are that i get errors from devise sign_in function and sign_out

when i call sign out (destroy) I get this message:

> TypeError in Accounts::SessionsController#destroy

and also:

> wrong argument type Symbol (expected String)

my session controller is of course empty:

```
class Accounts::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    root_url
  end
end
```

what can it be?.. please advise, thanks.

edit:
devise and omniauth gems im using:

```
# authentication
gem 'devise', '2.2.3'
gem 'devise-encryptable', '0.1.1'

# oauth authentication
gem 'omniauth', '1.1.3'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.1'
gem 'omniauth-twitter', '0.0.14'
gem 'omniauth-openid', '1.0.1'
```

Comment: did you update your devise gem?

Comment: not enough info to answer the question. use pry or better_errors to find out what exactly is the problem

Comment: ok tnx ill try. ill add info once i have it

Comment: ok this had nothing to do with devise.. using better_erors and binding_of_caller gems i was able to find the problem. om my user.rb object i have this line: 'serialize :timestamps, Hash'
if i comment it out everything works. why is that? why is this line causing the app to crash?